# Trying to isolate a variable in a differential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to isolate the derivative of a function y(x) here so I may integrate to find the function in terms of y ( on python ).
So in order to do that, I need to either isolate the y'(x) (the derivative) or just somehow get rid of the root. Any ideas?
Everything besides 'x' in the exponential is a constant, so don't worry about that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wJCs.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isolating the square root we obtain
$$\sqrt{(y'^2+1)}=-y'+e^{-g/T\left(mx^2/2+cx\right)}$$
squaring both sides we get
$$y'^2+1=y'^2-2y'e^{g/T\left(mx^2/2+cx\right)}+e^{2g/T\left(mx^2/2+cx\right)}$$
and you can cancel $$y'^2$$ on b oth sides. Can you proceed?